# DEAD LOCK issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I'm receiving some deadlock errors and this update is the one sql server chooses to kill

```
   UPDATE Dealer_Balance  
   SET Balance = COALESCE(EndBalance,0),   
   Deposit = COALESCE(EndDeposit,0),  
   Overdraft = COALESCE(EndOverdraft,0)  
   FROM Dealer_Balance WITH (ROWLOCK,HOLDLOCK)  
   INNER JOIN @BalanceTable AS BalanceTable ON  
   Dealer_Balance.DealerID = BalanceTable.ContractorID  
   END
```

I'm kinda lost here, what should I be looking for in my BD? Does variable tables have any lock issues?

Before this update I have the query below in the same procedure:

```
 INSERT INTO @BalanceTable  
 (ContractorType, ContractorID, StartBalance, EndBalance, CurBalance, 
 StartDeposit, EndDeposit, CurDeposit, StartOverdraft, EndOverdraft,   
 CurOverdraft, TransferDate, PayType)  
 SELECT   
 AccountChange.ContractorType, AccountChange.ContractorID, 
 Dealer_Balance.Balance AS StartBalance,   
 (Dealer_Balance.Balance + COALESCE(AccountChange.BalanceChange, 0)) AS 
 EndBalance, NULL AS CurBalance, Dealer_Balance.Deposit AS StartDeposit,   
 (Dealer_Balance.Deposit + COALESCE(AccountChange.DepositChange,0)) AS 
 EndDeposit, NULL AS CurDeposit, Dealer_Balance.Overdraft,   
 (Dealer_Balance.Overdraft + COALESCE(AccountChange.OverdraftChange,0)) 
 AS EndOverdraft, NULL AS CurOverdraft,   
 COALESCE(@AdvancedOverrideTransferDate,GetDate()) AS TransferDate, 
 AccountChange.PayType  
 FROM Dealer_Balance WITH (ROWLOCK,HOLDLOCK)--(ROWLOCK,XLOCK)   
 INNER JOIN @AccountChangeTable AS AccountChange ON   
 Dealer_Balance.DealerID = AccountChange.ContractorID
```

Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: Try to reproduce the deadlock while running a SQL Trace/Profiler... making sure you have the Deadlock events and Deadlock graph event selected. It'll give you exact information on what processes deadlocked, and what object they deadlocked over. Selecting RCP Completed as well, and you can see exactly what SQL each process was executing when the deadlock occurred. This is where you start.

Comment: I've done that already, and right before the deadlock message the trace shows the update I've posted for the same spid. I could not find the other query that was locking it, just that the one above was choosen as the deadlock victim.

Comment: It tells you the two spids that are involved in the deadlock. Scroll back through the trace to find the last thing the other spid did, and you'll have the other SQL. Further, the deadlock graph event will show you a pictoral representation, including the IDs of exactly what is locking. This can help you focus your search.